# How to run golang server in docker

Tags: docker, go

I setup a simple server with golang:

```
package main

import (
    "golang-server/database"
    "golang-server/helper"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    database.Connect()
    port := helper.GetPort()

    SetupRoutes()

    log.Printf("connect to http://localhost:%s/ for GraphQL playground", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router))

}
```

Here is what my folder structure look like:

[image]

Here is what my dockerfile look like:

```
FROM golang:1.18

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src

COPY . .

RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o /golang-server

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["golang-server"]
```

I am running these docker commands in the main directory:

```
docker build . -t golang-server 

docker run --network=golang-server --name=golang-server golang-server
```

However I am getting this error when I run:

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "golang-server": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

What should I set the dockerfile so I can successfully deploy to docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related with your last line in Dockerfile `CMD ["golang-server"]`. When you put it there, the system (inside of the container) are trying to find an executable file inside of your `$PATH` variable called `golang-server`.

To solve this issue, you can just edit your last line from your Dockerfile to `CMD ["/golang-server"]`, once you are building your application in `/` (`RUN go build -o /golang-server`). The final Dockerfile should be something like:

```
FROM golang:1.18

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src

COPY . .

RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o /golang-server

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/golang-server"]
```